# Comparing Azure table data against Cosmos Db

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-cosmosdb

We need to do a weekly sync of data in an Azure SQL table into a Cosmos db table. The Azure SQL table is the source and has millions of records. Has anyone done this before and was there a tool used to do this?

Comment: have you tried azure data factory (ADF v2) (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-cosmos-db)

Answer (score 0):

Surely,i'd suggest you using [Copy activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview) in Azure Data Factory which is applied for data transfer. You could configure Azure SQL DB as source and Cosmos db as sink. Please see the document:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview#supported-data-stores-and-formats

For your need, you need to do a weekly sync of data so you could create a [schedule trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-pipeline-execution-triggers#schedule-trigger) for the copy activity.